# Sphinx Stemming "finicky"?

Tags: sphinx, stemming

I just installed the en.pak and (as per a recently posted question) I matched

```
Radiography
```

to

```
Radiograph
Radiographic
Radiograper
```

However I rotated again and now somehow it stopped working. The only error message I see is

```
"WARNING: index 'idx_X': dict=keywords and prefixes and morphology enabled, forcing index_exact_words=1"
```

I commented out morphology (#) just in case but still somehow and all of a sudden Radiography only finds itself.

Interesting update. I tested on

```
Run
```

and it found

```
Run
Ran
Running
```

and tested on

```
Office
```

and it found

```
Office
Offices
```

But it failed to get

```
Proctologist
```

When I searched on

```
Proctology
```

My settings is

```
morphology = lemmatize_en_all
```

and installed the en.pak so is there some 'advanced' setting needed to get stems from words like 'ology' since it clearly is getting basic plurals and lems for Ran/Run/Running?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that lemmatize is not ideal for the types of suffix matches I am looking for and that stem_en is a better choice for this. When I changed morphology to stem_en radiology matches radiologist and also did not match radiography